# How to change the content of a tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

in my Tabhost there is an next button which should display a new page but in the same tab,
For this I created a two LinearLayout will be visible and when I click next the other will be visible.

Eclipse requires me to final for two LinearLayout And second when I tested it not change the content.

```
Button btsuiv= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsuivant);
Button btprec= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnprec);

final LinearLayout etap1= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.etap1);
final LinearLayout etap2= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.etap2);

btsuiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      etap1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      etap2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
});

btprec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {            
      etap1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      etap2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
});
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, but try View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE.

Comment: I'have 25 points and that was very kind to remove my points because you did not understand my question, because my bad english.
I found the solution is that I have to use the intents.

Comment: I am sorry about that but you see according to the forum rules, your question should help you and others and also make sense to people who are taking time out to help you.

Comment: anyway it is edited !! and i hope it will be clear :)

Comment: Awesome :) There you go! Makes so much more sense now. And now that you have an answer. Add it as an answer to your question. It will help others facing the same problem.

"The IDE me to impose the final for two LinearLayout And second when I tested it not change the content." This line still doens't make sense. Can you change it plz.

Comment: :( Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: Damn! Add it as an edit to your post or add it after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Android has ActivityGroup for the same purpose that you are looking for. By using ActivityGroup you can show multiple views in a single Tab by maintaining the stack of the Views.

[ActivityGroup Example 1](http://androidgenuine.com/)

[ActivityGroup Example 2](http://richipal.com/post/2624844577)

[Fragment doc](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html)